# php gd library to reveal background image

Tags: overlay, gd

I have two identical sized images that I would like to work with.  One image is in color, the other is in black and white.  I need assistance on stacking the color image directly over the black and white image.  After that, I would like to be able to remove sections of the top photo to reveal the image underneath.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help:

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/how-do-i-merge-various-images-into-one-using-gd-502604.html

Especially the part that talks about adding watermarking.

You will have to add transparent areas to the top image before combining them.

lee